# Run Component specific Angular Test Cases

Tags: angular, unit-testing, components

When we run

> ng Test

It runs the tests for all the components in the project. 
Say we have 2 components in my project 1: App, 2: Test

What if i want to run the tests only in test.component.specs.ts?

Comment: if it is a temproary thing you can use the `f` *focused* prefix on both `describe` and the `it` if you want to run only a single test, that will run only the fixture or test you want. check it out @ [focused_specs.js](https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/focused_specs.html) other option is to edit the configfile to use only that file, or use a custom one and use the `--config-file` option `ng test --config-file=your-custom-config.ts`